# Make content node primary parent of node

Tags: java, alfresco

I try to use the Alfresco `NodeService` to make a content node (QName `cm:content`) the **primary parent** of another content node. `NodeService` provides a method

```java
public ChildAssociationRef moveNode(
        NodeRef nodeToMoveRef,
        NodeRef newParentRef,
        QName assocTypeQName,
        QName assocQName)
        throws InvalidNodeRefException;
```

Let's say the current primary parent of the  node `theNodeToMove` is a **folder** and the primary parent assoc reference of the node in the folder is `primaryAssocRef`. Let `theTargetContentNode` be the target **content** node.

Calling the above message like this

```java
nodeService.moveNode(theNodeToMove,
                     theTargetContentNode,
                     primaryAssocRef.getTypeQName(),
                     primaryAssocRef.getQName());
```

fails. Alfresco reporst an **integrity violation**:

```
The association source type is incorrect:
   Source Node: workspace://SpacesStore/27a97736-222c-4bac-8610-f15ce312b074 
   Association: Association[ class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder], name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source role=null, target role=null]
   Required Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder
   Actual Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}content
```

Is it even possible to make a **content node** the **primary parent** of an **existing** content node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. Yes because content node can have children, and no because you can't use the "contains" association.

Basically, when you create a "parent-child" relation, you need to state it's association type. You can have as many of these, for instance `rm:rendition` is one of these types.

The "main" association type used when you create a document under a folder is `cm:contains`, and is setup in a way that does not allow content nodes to have children. This is done through model definition, and looks something like this:

```
<type name="cm:folder">
     <title>Folder</title>
     <parent>cm:cmobject</parent>
     <archive>true</archive>
     <associations>
        <child-association name="cm:contains">
           <source>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </source>
           <target>
              <class>sys:base</class>
              <mandatory>false</mandatory>
              <many>true</many>
           </target>
           <duplicate>false</duplicate>
           <propagateTimestamps>true</propagateTimestamps>
        </child-association>
     </associations>
</type>
```

Comment: A folder can obviously have many children via the contains relationship and those children can have children. Nodes can also have multiple parents. What do you mean when you say that the cm:contains association is "setup in a way that does not allow content nodes to have children"?